# How to know a device is available to use captureTextFromCamera API?

Tags: ios, swift

iOS 15 supports `captureTextFromCamera` API to capture text from camera.But some devices don't supports such as iPhoneX.So How can I know this device supports `captureTextFromCamera` or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple condition:

```swift
UITextField().canPerformAction(#selector(UIResponder.captureTextFromCamera(_:))
```

Tests both device support and language setting support

Comment: Thx , this answer seems to be better, I 'll take a try

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 16 Apple add a new way to check Live Text support `ImageAnalyzer.isSupported`

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the device supports Live Text for images.

Apple Official Document: [VisionKit/ImageAnalyzer/isSupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/imageanalyzer/3974561-issupported)