# Check if Apple LiveText is available?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, livetext

I want to add apple live text support using a scan button. But I know that it is available for iOS 15+ and A12 processors and above. How do I check that in Swift?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking

Comment: Thanks. That way I can check the iOS version. But is there anyway of checking processor is above A12 or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know a device is available to use captureTextFromCamera API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69702884/how-to-know-a-device-is-available-to-use-capturetextfromcamera-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't check for the iOS 15+ and processor A12+, check for the iOS 15's 'Live Text'feature support. Create a helper method with the following check that will return whether the device support live text or not

---

#### Sample:

```swift
var isSupported = true
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    let check = UITextField().canPerformAction(#selector(UIResponder.captureTextFromCamera(_:)), withSender: nil)
    isSupported = check
} else {
    isSupported = false
}

print(isSupported)
```

Using the above condition will return `false` in the case of the device having iOS 15+ but not having hardware support.